# WebDeploy runcommand issue

Tags: webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy a package with WebDeploy V3. 
The installation process is to sync between a source folder to a destination folder on the remote computer and run a certain powershell script after the sync is done. 
The command being executed is:

```
'"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:dirPath='C:\source' -dest:dirPath='D:\destination',computerName=XXX -postSync:runcommand='powershell -inputformat none D:\destination\Install.ps1',successReturnCodes=0'
```

This yields the following error:

```
Info: Using ID '49edd786-d8a0-4acf-be7b-95dd6e1391cc' for connections to the remote server.  Performing '-postSync'... Info: 
Using ID '5ef9d005-82fa-4811-9f51-1741c8d622de' for connections to the remote server. 
Info: Adding MSDeploy.runCommand (MSDeploy.runCommand). 
Error: (11/28/2012 4:34:24 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. Error: The entry type 'Unknown' was not expected at this time. The serialization stream may be corrupted.
Error count: 1.
Error during '-postSync'.  Total changes: 0 (0 added, 0 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)
```

Searching the net for this error, I didn't see anybody who encountered it when using runcommand provider. If anybody encountered a similar issue and has ideas or suggestions I would be most thankful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, using `runCommand` to execute an arbitrary command line might be a bit buggy. Try moving the commandline into a `bat` or `cmd` file and providing a (full?) path to that. The file will be uploaded and executed, as long as you don't try to pass in any arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers of this post: I encountered this same specific error (`Error: The entry type 'Unknown' was not expected at this time. The serialization stream may be corrupted`) after adding runCommand provider usage to my MyProject.wpp.targets file for the Web Publishing Pipeline MSBuild process. The path was direct cmd shell input used in order to clear readonly flags with `attrib -R`.

In my case, my build server was configured with WebDeploy 3.0, while the server targeted by the deployment package was configured with Webdeploy 2.0. After upgrading the target server to Webdeploy 3.0 this particular problem was resolved.

However due to other errors surrounding runCommand (providing the correct path to the destination executable at package runtime) my solution still doesn't work entirely so take this all with a grain of salt.